# How grafana import old data when I restart prometheus?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I use grafana to show metrics from prometheus.

But when I restart prometheus server, grafana will not draw data that scraped before.

How make grafana draw all data that scraped from prometheus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think Grafana know or care about Prometheus restarts. Are you running Prometheus in a docker? Do you have the Prometheus storage set to a persistent storage. Grafana will just graph the data it gets from the respective data store.

Comment: Thank  for your reply.I run Prometheus in a docker.When I run it in host, Grafana will draw all data.

Comment: You're probably saving the Prometheus data INSIDE the docker, so when you're restarting it, all data is lost. You *should* set Prometheus to store its data OUTSIDE the docker. that way you can still have it run inside docker, and keep the data even after restarts.

Comment: Correct. Just mount a volume for default data dir /prometheus and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer should be addressed here: [How to persist data in Prometheus running in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009065/how-to-persist-data-in-prometheus-running-in-a-docker-container)

In a nutshell, you need to launch prometheus docker by mounting its volume data (`/prometheus/` by default) in a persistent way, so you don't lose data upon restart. I smashed my head over it a week, and finally I got it to work :)