# How to persist data in Prometheus running in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, persistence, prometheus

I'm developing something that needs Prometheus to persist its data between restarts. Having followed the instructions

```
$ docker volume create a-new-volume
$ docker run \
    --publish 9090:9090 \
    --volume a-new-volume:/prometheus-data \
    --volume "$(pwd)"/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    prom/prometheus
```

I have a valid `prometheus.yml` in the right directory on the host machine and it's being read by Prometheus from within the container. I'm just scraping a couple of HTTP endpoints for testing purposes at the moment.

But when I restart the container it's empty, no data from the previous run. What am I missing from my `docker run ...` command to persist the data into the `a-new-volume` volume?

Comment: Isn't `/prometheus` the right data dir?

Comment: Yes! What's your source for that info?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use the default data dir, which is `/prometheus`. To do that, use this line instead of what you have in your command:

```
...
--volume a-new-volume:/prometheus \
...
```

Found here: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/Dockerfile

Surprisingly is not mentioned in the [image docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus/)

Comment: when I do this, container failed to start. I realized it was because permissions of directory on host machine.

Comment: To save someone the trouble to figure out the permission: if you are using bind mount to mount a host directory: `chown` the folder to `nobody`.

Comment: Alternatively `chown 65534:65534 <volume-dir>`

Comment: There is a pull request for adding this info to the official installation docs: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/8747

Comment: That PR _finally_ just got merged! (after more than 2 years)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue a today, but I was using a docker composer file. So wrapping up all what was in comments of other answers and what worked for me. In case setting up the Prometheus docker via `yaml` compose file...

First create a folder for the volume on the host machine, e.g.:

```sh
$ mkdir /tmp/prometheus
```

Then change the folder owner to `nobody`, like (use `sudo` if needed):

```sh
$ chown 65534:65534 /tmp/prometheus
```

Then add volume to the `yaml` configuration file:

```
prometheus:
  image: prom/prometheus
  container_name: prometheus
  ports:
    - 9090:9090
  volumes:
    - /tmp/prometheus:/prometheus
    - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

That should do it.